# How to use Pipe passed as @Input in HTML template

Tags: angular

I made a reusable Component that accepts an array of a certain class. Now I want to pass a Pipe to this Component that will transform each element of that array into the visual representation I want. (This changes depending on the class of the array objects).

Now I don't know how to use this Pipe directly in the template. I managed to get it to work with an extra function that calls the pipe programmatically:

```
export class SingleCategoryFilterComponent<T> implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  possibleFilterValues: T[];
  @Input()
  displayPipe: PipeTransform;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  transformValue(value: T) {
    return this.displayPipe.transform(value);
  }

}
```

and the (partial) template:

```
<button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let value of possibleFilterValues">
    {{transformValue(value)}}
</button>
```

But I would prefer to not have to create this transform function, and just be able to do something like:

```
<button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let value of possibleFilterValues">
    {{value | displayPipe}}
</button>
```

but that doesn't seem to work, as displayPipe is not registered. Is there a way to use the variable @Input displayPipe in the template?

Comment: As far as I know Angular, this is not possible. What you can do is remove this transformValue method and use {{ displayPipe.transform(value) }} directly in the template. I had the same problem you have now and didn't find a better solution.

Comment: That doesnt make a big difference at all

Comment: is there any reason that you dont want to have the transformValue method?

Comment: Using the transform function directly in the template seems acceptable to me (for some reason I didn't think of something quite obvious...). And as for not wanting the transformValue method, it seems like unnecessary extra code, cluttering the actual useful stuff. I just always try to find out the best way to do things, for future reference for both myself and others stumbling upon this.

Answer (score 3):

How about if you use a wrapper pipe that takes care of this for you in the template and you pass in the `displayPipe` pipe as an argument of the pipe's `transform` method. Something like below (might need some sort of tweaking to suit your question, but you get the idea)

In template,

```
<button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let value of possibleFilterValues">
    {{value | wrappingPipe:displayPipe}}
</button>
```

The wrapper pipe,

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'wrappingPipe'
})
export class WrappingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, displayPipe?: PipeTransform): any {
    if(value !== undefined) {
      return displayPipe && displayPipe.transform ? displayPipe.transform(value) : value;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let value of possibleFilterValues">
    {{displayPipe.transform(value)}}
</button>
```

works for me.

It's not the

> {{value | displayPipe}}

you were looking for, but it's the shortest solution Ive found.